# Having trouble reading data from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I don't understand how to read the genre data.

```
"data":
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "type": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "url": "string"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "url": "string"
    }
  ],
}
```

I want it to end up being displayed like
`name1, name2, name3`
and (if possible) I want to have each of the names have the link to their corresponding url.

I have tried to find that data by

```
var genres = data.genres;
```

But that just returns `[object Object],[object Object]`
Im guessing that you have to read the data from those objects, but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to understand from that is the following: "data" is an object and it has a "genres" property which has an array of objects inside it. Knowing this you can just do the following:

```
const name1 = data.genres[0].name; // Gets the first name
const name2 = data.genres[1].name; // Gets the second name
```

If you want to loop through the genre data, then you need to iterate through the objects inside the "genres" property:

```
data.genres.map((genre) => console.log(genre.name)); // Logs all names
```

This would be a more common example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.genres.length; i++) {
    const name = data.genres[i].name;
    console.log(name); // Logging the names
}
```

Comment: Could I take the output of `data.genres.map((genre) => console.log(genre.name));` and put it into a string. E.g. `name1, name2, name3`

Comment: Of course, you can. Look up how to concatenate an array of strings (with a separator) in JS. `data.genres.map((genre) => genre.name)` will return an array of names such as `['John', 'Joe']`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop to go through the data, and create a-elements to create a link. You'll also need a parent element to append the links to:

```
const yourParentElement = document.getElementById("parent");
var genres = data.genres;
genres.forEach(genre => { 
    var lnkGenre = document.createElement("a"); 
    lnkGenre.textContent = genre.name;
    lnkGenre.href = genre.url;
```

You can also add classes or an id here:

```
    lnkGenre.classList.add("yourClass");
    lnkGenre.id = genre.id;
    yourParentElement.appendChild(lnkGenre);
});
```